# How to enable circular navigation on HTML Select?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrow-keys

I would think this is a pretty basic requirement, but I can't seem to find a single post about this.

I have a simple html `select` element on my page, when the user presses arrow down, the selection moves very nicely downwards.

What I want to do is that when the user reaches the last option and presses down again, the selection should jump to the first item. and vice versa.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here are my current attempts

```
<select onKeyDown={(e) => {
var a = 1;
}}
onKeyPress={(e) => {
var a = 1;
}}
>
{options.map((rec) => (
<option
  value={rec.Key}
  key={rec.Key}
  onFocus={() => {
    var a = 1;
  }}
  onKeyDown={() => {
    var a = 1;
  }}
>
  {rec.Value}
</option>
))}
</select>;
```

none on the events fire

Comment: You can check the focus and when its hitting the last child option set the focus to first one
if you provide live example i show you how to implement it

Comment: I believe that probably isn't something you can control with a standard `select` element. Those are usually rendered using the operation systems standard control, which the browser has only limited control over.  You may want to consider using one of the many replacement JavaScript components that are available around the web.

Comment: @ShobiDobi Thanks. I added my testing. the events don't seem to fire. Please advise.